# ArrayList not displaying to ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

So I have a `SQLite` `database`, and an `ArrayList` and I'm using the following code to pull values and store them into another `ArrayList`

the error I'm getting is an `NPE` `Null Pointer Exception` to this method when I try and display it to my listview

It should display the following:

```
Home: 24
Work: 2
School: 0
```

etc etc

The getLocationsArray method returns all the locations and my `query` returns the amount of times each location has been smoked at. I've checked both those with `Log.v` and they display the correct values.

So why won't this display to my `ListView`?

Comment: Did you instantiate mySmokinDatabase?

Comment: Have you instantiated the `myLocations` anywhere. The code in the OP seems to be missing `ArrayList<String> myLocations = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: yes I just thought of the instantiating of the `db`, and I tried it, code is updated to show it. It still gives me the same error. The `ArrayList` was always declared

Comment: @IrishWhiskey: Try moving the `ArrayList<String> myLocations = new ArrayList<String>();` into the `getLocations()`

Comment: @SiddharthLele I don't see why that would help. Never the less I tried it, and it still does not work. Same error

Comment: Check if listView is null.

Comment: @HoanNguyen how do I do that?

Comment: after findViewById line just put if(listView == null) and log it.

Comment: @HoanNguyen oh, lol. I thought I could just check another way. Alright

Comment: No, the listview is not null

Comment: Post your logcat. I guess aa must be null then.

Comment: Remove the <String> in aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>

Comment: I put the above as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if you use model anywhere else in your database thus I instantiate it on the constructor.

```
public MySmokinDatabase (Context context) {
smokinDBOpenHelper = new SmokinDBOpenHelper(context, SmokinDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_NAME, 
        null, SmokinDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
model = new Model();
}
```

Comment: sorry sir, this doesn't work either. I get the exact same logcat

Comment: The logcat said getLocations(MySmokinDatabase.java:144) is null. Double click on that line in the logcat to see the exact line in your code.

Comment: Is it on the line for (String s : model.getLocationsArray())?

Comment: line 144: 'for (String s : model.getLocationsArray()) {'

line 28 is also to blame, its this line

line28: `mySmokinDatabase = new MySmokinDatabase(this);`

Comment: so model is null or getLocationArray() returns null.

Comment: You said that, it made perfect sense. I have a restore model method. I called it and I was so excited and then.. nothing. Same npe. I will update my post to show the changes

Comment: I accepted, and I thank you yet again. Now you've done quite enough, but would you mind telling me why I need to `instantiate` my `model.java` inside my `database` `constructor`?

Comment: If you use it any where else in your MySmokinDatabase class. Actually you can instantiate it at public static Model model = new Model(); If you do not use it anywhere else in your MySmokinDatabase class except on getLocations() then you should remove it as a class member and inside getLocations() put Model model = new Model();

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you for your time. I'd upvote you a lot more if I could